Applying a rowwise str_split doesn't work
I have a character column containing email adresses in one single string (separated by comma).
I have another character column that also contains such email addresses.
I now want to split up the character string in the first column (i.e. creating a vector of email addresses) and then check if any of these appear in the second column.
I thought this is an easy task for stringr functions, but it seems they are not vetorized in a way I thought they would be.
I know how I can achieve my task with other workarounds (e.g. separating longer etc.), but I'm interested in one single call without reshaping anything.
Data:
df <- structure(list(a = c("a@test.com, b@test.com", "x@test.com, y@test.com"),
                     b = c("b@test.com, c@test.com", "d@test.com, e@test.com")),
                class = "data.frame",
                row.names = c(NA, -2L))

My code:
df |>
  mutate(test = any(str_detect(a, str_split_1(b, ", "))))

Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `test = any(str_detect(a, str_split_1(b, ", ")))`.
Caused by error in `str_split_1()`:
! `string` must be a single string, not a character vector.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

It seems str_split_1 doesn't recognize the single string per row and instead is taking the character vector of the whole column.
Expected output:
                       a                      b  test
1 a@test.com, b@test.com b@test.com, c@test.com  TRUE
2 x@test.com, y@test.com d@test.com, e@test.com FALSE


You could split the string, and then try detect each sub-string in a:
df %>%
 mutate(test = map_lgl(.x = str_split(b, ", "), ~ any(str_detect(a, str_escape(.x)))))

                       a                      b  test
1 a@test.com, b@test.com b@test.com, c@test.com  TRUE
2 x@test.com, y@test.com d@test.com, e@test.com FALSE

Or could replace the separator with | and search for each sub-string in a:
df %>%
 mutate(test = str_detect(a, str_replace(str_escape(b), ", ", "|")))


Thanks, I will check this out. One more question, would this also work if I put my call into a case_when? I.e. when I want to create a new column in a way where I say...case_when(any(str_detect....) == TRUE ~ 1, a == "x@test.com" ~ 2, TRUE ~ 3)...)

The second solution does return TRUE and FALSE on my computer. However, you would probably need to escape some special characters. I included that now.

For you example, probably you can try
> transform(df, test = unname(Vectorize(grepl)(sub(",\\s+", "|", b), a)))
                       a                      b  test
1 a@test.com, b@test.com b@test.com, c@test.com  TRUE
2 x@test.com, y@test.com d@test.com, e@test.com FALSE


Adding a call to rowwise() can get you your result.
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(a = c("a@test.com, b@test.com", "x@test.com, y@test.com"),
                     b = c("b@test.com, c@test.com", "d@test.com, e@test.com")),
                class = "data.frame",
                row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df |> rowwise() |> 
  mutate(test = any(str_detect(a, str_split_1(b, ", "))))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   a                      b                      test 
#>   <chr>                  <chr>                  <lgl>
#> 1 a@test.com, b@test.com b@test.com, c@test.com TRUE 
#> 2 x@test.com, y@test.com d@test.com, e@test.com FALSE

Created on 2024-10-22 with reprex v2.1.1

If we want to loop, we can do
> t(mapply(`%in%`, strsplit(df0$a, ", "), strsplit(df0$b, ", ")))
      [,1]  [,2]
[1,] FALSE TRUE
[2,] FALSE FALSE

We might want to run rowSums() on the result, e.g.
> transform(df0, test = rowSums(t(mapply(`%in%`, strsplit(a, ", "), strsplit(b, ", ")))))
                       a                      b test
1 a@test.com, b@test.com b@test.com, c@test.com    1
2 x@test.com, y@test.com d@test.com, e@test.com    0

We can avoid loops alltogether if we want to.
